# Is there any convenient way of converting WPF project to iOS desktop application?

Tags: ios, .net, wpf

I have developed a `WPF` application which is run on windows platform. But my client wants the same desktop application on `iOS` platform. How can I do that without developing a new application?

Comment: I have googled a lot but failed to a solution. I just want to know is that possible or not. But why am I getting downvoted here?

Answer (score 1):

You cann't convert WPF project to iOS application. You cant try to reimplement your app on [xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/).